# SSH connection hangs in Mac OS Terminal - No prompt for password

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, wireless

I've been SSH'ing into my Raspi 3 B+ for some time now from my Mac OS with no issues.

I recently set a static IP address for my Pi on a LAN network connected via ethernet cable. I edited
`sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

and then added at the bottom;

`interface eth0
static ip_address=my.desired.ip.address
static routers=router.address
static domain_name_servers=DNS.address`

Where my router address and DNS address were retrieved using
`route -n` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` respectively.

I successfully SSH'd from a different laptop onto my Pi using this static IP address - this network is not connected to the internet.

**Going back to my personal laptop which is on a wireless network (same as Pi) which is connected to the internet. I tried SSH'ing into my Pi as normal but the connection hangs.**

I've confirmed my Pi's IP address with `ifconfig wlan0` which is `198.123.52.xx`. When I try through terminal to SSH using `sudo ssh pi@198.123.52.xx -v` I get the following;

`OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 198.123.52.xx [198.123.52.xx] port 22.`

The connection just hangs there.

- I've tried reinstalling SSH-server with
  `sudo apt-get purge ssh-server` then `sudo apt-get install ssh-server`.
- I've tried adding `IPQoS cs0 cs0` to the end of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.
- I've `#` commented out the static ip changes I made.
- I've run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` - All packages are installed and updated.

Do I need to remove a hostkey or flush something?

I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Can you ping the Pi? Setting an incomplete/wrong static address is one of the common problems, but as you haven't told us what you did who knows? Purging and re-installing files just makes things worse. PS there is **ABSOLUTELY** no point in trying to obscure a **Private IP address** but using a NASA IP range is unlikely to work.

Comment: Always better to setup the static IP address in the router. Not on the device itself. That way you won't hit your toe again.

Comment: You gave a static ip address to the wired interface **eth0**. Then you wrote "*my personal laptop which is on a wireless network (same as Pi)*". Do you connect the RasPi one time wired, the other time wireless? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: What is the output of `traceroute PIADDRESS` on the mac ?

Comment: @Ingo Yeah, I'm working on a wireless network connected to the internet, but set up the static eth0 ip address on a separate network that is not connected to the internet  where the Pi is tethered.

Comment: @Milliways Yeah I can ping the Pi, and the Pi can ping my laptop. 
I deleted the code that I added to set the static ip address within the `dhcpcd.conf` file and rebooted.  Double checked and its gone.

Comment: @craig when I run traceroute PIADDRESS on my Mac terminal I get the following;
`traceroute 198.123.52.116traceroute to 198.123.52.116 (198.123.52.116), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *`
When I run it through Network Utility I get;
`Traceroute has started…

traceroute to 198.123.52.116 (198.123.52.116), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  Raspberry Pi (198.123.52.116)  7.015 ms  5.157 ms  3.929 ms`

Comment: Please don't use comments for additional information. It is unreadable. Instead edit your question and add it there. I suggest to take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: What do you mean with "*...where the Pi is tethered*"? Do you use an USB cable to your smartphone with tethering enabled or do you use wifi to connect to an internet router? On the wired port (**eth0**) you have an ethernet cable plugged in. Where is the other end of the cable plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

I think your choice of address -- 198.123.52.xx is the problem. That is a valid routable IP address **that is assigned to NASA**. This could work as long as you are not connected to internet.

However, if your mac is connected to internet then it will likely try to contact that IP by routing to the internet not your local network.

You need to select a netblock reserved for private networks (see [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)).

- 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
- 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
- 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix) List item